# How to trigger a workflow from an incoming email to a document library

Tags: workflow, document-library, approval-process, email-enabled-library

I have been trying a bunch of different stuff to get this to work, lots of great info here.   I thought I might as well ask to get some answers for sure or see if anybody had any ideas!

Some background:  SharePoint 2013; I'm creating a change management record system by allowing my group to email the description of what they are changing, along with any supporting documents as attachments, to a SharePoint document library made specifically for this purpose.

The document library is email-enabled, and when emailing to it, a folder with the email subject is created, which inside contains a ".eml" copy of the email body/text and any attachments that were on the email.

--This is all working as intended so far--

Now, I'm trying to attach an Approval workflow to it such that the members of the team get sent a message with a link to the email item (or maybe just the folder, I'm open to whatever works) along with the Outlook "Open this Task..." link up at the top for approve/reject/etc.

This setup works exactly as intended if:

- 1) The workflow is set up as "Document" or "This List" and configured to kick off on "item created"
- 2) There are NO attachments (i.e. the folder in the library contains only the .eml file).  If there *are* attachments, it triggers a workflow for EVERY item... I just want one workflow per 'submission'.

I've tried setting up the workflow based on "Folder" and "item created", since that *seems* to be what the email does, but nothing ever triggers in that configuration.

I've also considered using "Document Sets" -- since this is pretty much exactly the use case for them -- but there doesn't seem to be a way to change the "Incoming Email" settings to have it create a document set or something like that.

**tl;dr:**

- trying to set up workflow for incoming email
- incoming email groups items into folders by subject (.eml + attachments)
- doesn't trigger if set up as Folder workflow with "Start on item created"
- does trigger if set up as Document/This List workflow with "Start on item created"
- If set up as Document/This List, it triggers on each individual item rather than per email

Any ideas or insight on how I can get this to work how I envision?  Thanks!

Comment: Just an update to bring it full circle in case anyone ends up here in the future :)

The above suggestion was correct, the Sharepoint admins had to get involved.  The admin was awesome, and managed to tweak my workflow so it did exactly what I needed.

Thanks for the input!

Comment: I am looking to do something very similar...was this done with SP online?

Comment: No, this was with a local instance of Sharepoint on our own servers.  Not sure if the option exists on the cloud/hosted solution...

Comment: After much research...its doesnt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've run into this several times, it isn't enabled by default. It needs to be enabled via PowerShell:

```
$spWebService = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService]::ContentService
 $spWebService.DeclarativeWorkflowAutoStartOnEmailEnabled = $true
 $spWebService.Update()
```

Comment: Ah, got it.  So I should ask the SharePoint admins if "Declarative Worlflow Autostart on Email" is Enabled?

I assume they will need to be the ones to run the PS script...  but who knows, maybe it's already on -- I mean, an email *does* trigger a workflow if it's set to Document.  I will update when I find out.  Thanks!

Comment: Correct, the server admins need to check this.

Answer (score 0):

Small addition to that is that you check the status of this switch:

```
$spWebService = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService]::ContentService
$spWebService.DeclarativeWorkflowAutoStartOnEmailEnabled
```

Source: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/6a246070-b107-43bb-8c99-99fda4fccc1d/workflow-not-being-triggered-by-incoming-email?forum=sharepointgeneral