# Documents emailed to sharepoint library, then trigger a flow

Tags: flow

We are using a program that emails XML reports into a secure sharepoint library only accessible for internal people.

We are then using a flow to: 'when an item is created or modified in folder' send email to outside users and attach this XML report.

When we click and drag XML reports into the library this triggers the flow, however the XML reports **emailed** to the library do not trigger the flow.

Any ideas how to fix this? Are we missing something?

Comment: Is email enabled libraries still an option or is the program just creating the XML files using an api?

Comment: It is an email enabled library, the program runs reports and emails the report to the sharepoint library.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at following posts

[How to trigger a workflow from an incoming email to a document library](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/111087/how-to-trigger-a-workflow-from-an-incoming-email-to-a-document-library)

[Setting DeclarativeWorkflowAutoStartOnEmailEnabled to true](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/131235/setting-declarativeworkflowautostartonemailenabled-to-true/135136)

My colleague made this on our environment (SP2016 OnPrem) and it works well!